# Export variable from evaluate function in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to export min and max variables from evaluate function and use them for additional calculations.

How can obtain and use min and max values from outside of function?

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(43.45421663606079, 40.31807660792319, 45.278, 39.39)
var img = ee.Image("WWF/HydroSHEDS/03VFDEM").clip(geometry)
var minMax = img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(), 
             geometry: geometry, 
             scale: img.projection().nominalScale(),
             bestEffort: true,
             maxPixels: 1e9})

// It can be accessed min and max values like below code
// var minValue= ee.Number(minMax.get('b1_min'))
// var minValue= ee.Number(minMax.get('b1_min'))

// But i want to learn, how can export variables from outside the scope of the evaluate function

var min = 0
var max = 0
minMax.evaluate(function(val){
    min = val.b1_min;
    max = val.b1_max;
    print(min,max) // results are, 766, 5101
    })
    
var diff = max - min
print(diff) // result is 0
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1b6a94b7fb90465ca14f90fa9715ac3d

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear what you're actually asking for. I'm guessing that when you say that you want to "export min and max variables from evaluate function", you want to access `min` and `max` outside the scope of the function?

The function you pass to `evaluate()` is invoked asynchronously, so `var diff = max - min` has already been invoked by the time `min` and `max` is actually assigned.

You either have to do your work inside the function itself put your work into a separate function.

```
var min = 0
var max = 0
minMax.evaluate(function(val) {
  min = val.b1_min
  max = val.b1_max
  calculateDiff()
})

function calculateDiff() {
  var diff = max - min
  print(diff) // result is 0
}
```

This would be even better, in my opinion:

```
minMax.evaluate(function(val) {
  calculateDiff(val.b1_min, val.b1_max)
})

function calculateDiff(min, max) {
  var diff = max - min
  print(diff) // result is 0
}
```

You can always use `getInfo()` instead of `evaluate()`. That keeps things synchronous and simple, but it will block the interface.

Comment: i want to access min and max outside the scope of the function? Yes, Daniel...

Comment: @MehmetCARSLANOGLU, as you can see in this answer, you can access assigned values outside the scope of the callback function block. But you can't access them before the server answer to the evaluate method. Just don't close the callback function block until the end of the script, you can write all the code you want inside that block. And don't be mad at yourself for not understanding engine async.